# What is causing "Failed to initialize geis instance Aborted" when trying to run touchegg in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, gestures, touchegg

What is causing "Failed to initialize geis instance Aborted" when trying to run touchegg in Ubuntu 11.10?

I am trying to enable more gesture options for my mac-book touch pad on Ubuntu 11.10, and have come across the touchegg project. I have installed it but when I try to run touchegg from the command line I get the error I described earlier. Does anyone know what is causing this, or even better, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but did you try sudo?

Comment: No, shouldn't I get a permission denied error if that's the case? -- and no, it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I was using packaged from the release candidates stream where conflicts can arise because some packages don't have ports yet and thus break dependencies. I have moved back to the the regular updates stream and touchegg initialized just fine.